# Android Studio 3 does not show menu

Tags: macos, android-studio

Why does Android Studio 3 not show the menu on macOS?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You've some updation problem, may be not updated properly.

For me, there is no problems, try to uninstall and install again.

Image Reference :

[image]

**EDIT**

I've High Sierra and I don't have any issue but there is a similar known [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JRE-434#tab=Linked%20Issues) in jetbrain issue tracker.

The workaround by the time being is installing [Apple legacy Java 6 runtime](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572).

Comment: I tried to uninstall and install but it doesn't work.

Comment: @user8835358 which version of Mac os ?

Comment: 10.13.1 Beta (17B46a)